# How to execute a shell_exec command

Tags: php, html, powershell

I'm actually working on a PHP script that uses POST variables to execute a PowerShell script. But somehow, the script isn't launching.

I have tried a lot of of things with shell_exec:
-switching quote marks
-changing the path to the script
but nothing changed :/

```php
<?php
    //Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html"');
    //storaging the variables passed by POST
    $LastName = $_POST["LastName"];
    $FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $begin = $_POST["begin"];
    $end = $_POST["end"];
    $desc = $_POST["desc"];
    $command = shell_exec('./Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FirstName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true ');
?>
```

executing this is supposed to produce a PDF file but nothing comes out.
Is my shell_exec correct?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check `$FirstName` vs `FirstName "'.$FristName.'" -LastName "`

Comment: If you are going to allow users to enter information that is being passed to a shell you should at least run the command string through [`escapeshellarg()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before execution, otherwise you might be opening your server up to some nefarious and destructive behavior.

Comment: Typo corrected!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $command = shell_exec('powershell ./Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FristName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true ');
```

Appending the `powershell` to the beginning of the `shell_exec` function should yield the results you desire.

Comment: hey Linus! I tried this ``` shell_exec('powershell ./Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FirstName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true ')``` but nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in one of your variable names, that may be causing issues.

```
<?php
    //Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "Get-Process | ConvertTo-Html"');
    //storaging the variables passed by POST
    $LastName = $_POST["LastName"];
    $FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $begin = $_POST["begin"];
    $end = $_POST["end"];
    $desc = $_POST["desc"];

    /*
     * Use $FirstName, not $FristName
     */
    $command = shell_exec('./Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FirstName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true ');  
?>
```

Comment: Yep thanks for pointing it out! it's just a typo in my translation :p 
except that the code is fine!

Answer (score 0):

What is displayed at the exit?

```
 <?php
$output = shell_exec('Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FristName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

?>

Comment: for now, nothing the page is blank :/

Comment: tried ```shell_exec('powershell ./Script.ps1 -FirstName "'.$FirstName.'" -LastName "'.$LastName.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type.'" -AGOL $true ')```but it did nothing :<

Comment: and this `shell_exec('powershell ./Add-ADUserENSG1.ps1 -Prenom {$prenom} -NomFamille {$nom} -Description {$desc} -Type {$type} -AGOL $true ') ` ?

Comment: tried to change that and run it but I still got no file produced :/

Comment: Add .exe after powershell

Comment: the .exe didn't change the output

Comment: this doesn't work either ```exec('powershell ./Add-ADUserENSG1.ps1 -Prenom {$prenom} -NomFamille {$nom} -Description {$desc} -Type {$type} -AGOL $true ');```

Comment: And by putting "'.$FirstName.'" ?